# How do I add the timezone field to a profile?

Tags: profile

Timezone is one of the fields in the address table. I'd like to add it to a data entry profile but it's not listed in any of the dropdown menus. How can I add it to the profile even if it's not in the dropdown?

Comment: Is this a custom field for address?

Comment: @PradeepNayak, no. Timezone is a standard (not custom) field in the address table in the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not supported by CiviCRM but you can do a small change in your existing CiviCRM file as shown below and clear civicrm cache, the profile form should then should allow you to add timezone field of address.

```
diff --git a/CRM/Core/DAO/Address.php b/CRM/Core/DAO/Address.php
index b1e00a83dc..ee9bf2d945 100644
--- a/CRM/Core/DAO/Address.php
+++ b/CRM/Core/DAO/Address.php
@@ -731,6 +731,7 @@ class CRM_Core_DAO_Address extends CRM_Core_DAO {
           'table_name' => 'civicrm_address',
           'entity' => 'Address',
           'bao' => 'CRM_Core_BAO_Address',
+          'import' => TRUE,
           'localizable' => 0,
           'html' => [
             'type' => 'Text',
```

Comment: Thanks, @PradeepNayak. Works great! Might it also be useful to add `'export' => TRUE,`? I notice all of the other fields that are normally included in the Profile dropdown also that.

Comment: Looks like I responded to soon. The timecode field is in the Profile dropdown but data entered into that field doesn't get saved in the address table.